# How to preserve unique combination of two columns when inserting data in 3rd column?

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have three columns in mysql table: tax_id, company_name, store_name. I need that tax_id and company_name are unique combination and that tax_id or company_name couldn't exist in combination with another company_name or tax_id separately. Another thing is that I need to put in 3rd column names of different (all) stores that company has. Example of table should be:

```
tax_id| company_name| store_name
1324  | Kmart       | 1st ave
1324  | Kmart       | broadway
1324  | Kmart       | 5th ave
7725  | DM          | shop 1
7725  | DM          | shop 2
7725  | DM          | shop 7
etc...
```

Using tax_id with different company is forbidden or using company_name with different tax_id is forbidden. 
Any help is welcome, also any code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `tax_id` and `company_name` have one-to-one mapping, it is advised that you normalize your database. You should move `tax_id to company_name mapping` to a different table and keep either `company_name` or `tax_id` in the current table. You can use `JOIN` to squeeze out any information you want.

If you cannot change your db structure then you will have to query database for if the company_name has a tax_id and then use the subsequent information for the insert query.

For more information look at [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: could you illustrate your first option with some example

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 tables:

- companies
- stores

Companies contains tax_id and company_name.
Stores contains tax_id as a foreign-key and store_name.

Then you can make tax_id and company_name unique and tax_id primary